# sql error update Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'insert'

Tags: sql-server

assume i have 2 tables

```
table1(id,name,description,tid)
table2(id(autoincrement),value)

update table1 set tid=insert into table2 values('x') SELECT @@IDENTITY AS id
```

the above command is giving me an error.

Can you suggest a solution??

Comment: Are you sure you want to update table1.tid with an insert into another table ?? This does not make much sense

Comment: yes i am sure I want to update and insert last id inserted in table2

Comment: You want to update and insert into table1 at the same time ? My advice : first insert into table2 and then uptade table1 from a select from table2

Comment: solved the issue your correct but I wanted to do both at same time

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the statements up, and use `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY` instead:

```
INSERT INTO table2
VALUES('x')

UPDATE table1
SET tid = @@SCOPE_IDENTITY
```

`@@SCOPE_IDENTITY` will return the last identity value created within the current scope.  Make sure there's nothing in between the two statements.

Comment: Thanks for having translated my comment into an answer ;)